After done compillig how to use backspace, copy and paste in terminal in macvim?
I've set up  as my keybinding to compile C++ files in Vim/Neovim. However, after I press , the terminal opens as expected, but I'm encountering some strange behavior:
Backspace Key: When I try to use the backspace key, it doesn't delete characters but instead inputs ^H.

Copy and Paste Bindings: My usual keybindings for copying and pasting aren't working in the terminal. For instance, when I try to copy, it inputs \y instead.

I've already set 'set backspace=indent,eol,start', but this hasn't resolved the issue. I also tried changing my keybindings for copy and paste, but the problem persists.
Has anyone else experienced this, or does anyone know how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What you need is stty erase ^H.  Do you have that in your .zshrc (assuming you're using zsh)?

yes, I am using zsh and yes it wasn't set but i did add the line its still the same.
